# Clean controllers: preparing data for views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Consider I have a controller with an action which renders a view. The view needs data to render. I know the following ways to prepare and send it to the view:

1. **Using instance variables**

   ```
   class CitiesController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @cities = Cities.order(:name).limit(10)
     end
   end
   ```

   This is the default approach which can be found in [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), but it has some disadvantages:

   1. It makes the action code fat which becomes responsible not only for controller logic, but also for the data preparation.
   2. Views need to access this data through instance variables – those @-variables break the principle of least astonishment.
2. **Using helper methods**

   ```
   class CitiesController < ApplicationController
     helper_method :cities

     def index
     end

     def cities
       @cities ||= Cities.order(:name).limit(10)
     end
   end
   ```

   That's the way I prefer the most. It keeps action methods clean, so I may implement controller logic there not mixing it with data preparations in one method. Also, there's no need to use mysterious instance variables in views, making them isolated. However:

   1. The data preparations are still in the controller. It becomes unreadable when there are a lot of these helper methods, especially when they are relative to different actions/views.
   2. There's a need of having a unique name for each helper method. Say, I can't have a method called `products` which will return different data for different actions (of course, I can do it in one method, but it would look ugly).
3. **Using the facade pattern**

   Partially the problem is solved in this article: https://medium.com/p/d65b86cdb5b1
   But I didn't like this approach because it introduces a `@magic_facade_object` in views.
4. **Using inherited resources**

   It may look beautiful in examples, but in my opinion when it comes to the real code, controller code becomes a spaghetti-monster very fast. The other thing is that a page view usually needs not only the resource but also other data to render (sidebar blocks, etc.) and I still have to use another way to prepare it. Combining different approaches makes the code even more unreadable. Finally, I don't like to use `resource` variable, because it makes not very clear what is the view about.

So, here is the question. How do you keep your controllers clean?

Answer (score 3):

```
How do you keep your controllers clean?
```

By writing DRY code and sprinkling some gem magic around.

Having a look at your bullet points, I think I have a different opinion on most of the stuff.

1. `@cities = Cities.order(:name).limit(10)` is exactly what i think belongs into a rails controller and it does not violate the principle of least surprise, it's kind of the opposite. instance variables are the default way of passing around variables from controllers to views, even though that is a pretty ugly thing to do. it's "the rails way" (TM)!
2. [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) takes away most of these concerns
3. please stop applying old-school pattern to rails or ruby code. it's really just useful in large applications where you are struggling to keep sane with the amount of code that's within a single controller method. write clean code, test it thoroughly and you will be fine 80% of the time.
4. don't use "one size fits all" tools. most often, you need to write more configuration than you would need code to make it work. it's also getting a lot more complex through this kind of things.